# Trouble parsing XML with python

Tags: python, xml, beautifulsoup

I have parsed an XML file with BeautifulSoup in Python and I am having trouble extracting the data out of it. An example of the structure of the XML is below:

```
<Products page="0" pages="-1" records="27">
  <Product id="ABC001">
    <Name>This product name</Name>
    <Cur>USD</Cur>
    <Tag>Text</Tag>
    <Classes>
      <Class id="USD">
        <ClassCur>USD</ClassCur>
        <Identifier>XYZ123456</Identifier>
      </Class>
    </Classes>
  </Product>
  <Product id="XYZ002">
    <Name>That product name</Name>
    <Cur>EUR</Cur>
    <Tag>More Text</Tag>
    <Classes>
      <Class id="EUR">
        <ClassCur>EUR</ClassCur>
        <Identifier>VDSHG123456</Identifier>
      </Class>
    </Classes>
  </Product>
</Products>
```

The first thing I have been trying to accomplish but have so far failed to do is to extract all of the Product and Class id's  `"ABC001"`, `"XYZ002"` etc..

What I have tried is

```
products = soup.find_all("Product")

for p in products:
    print(p.find("name")) # gets the name tag
    print(p.find("cur")) # gets the cur tag
    # ...etc
```

However, I can't figure out how to access `id` within `Product`. For example, `p.find("product")` returns `None`.

Note that while I am using bs4 I don't *have* to - it's just that I have done a lot of web scraping with Python + bs4 and have found bs4 to be useful in navigating through HTML, so assumed it would be the ideal way of handling XML.

Comment: Show us the code you've tried so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`id` is an attribute of `Product`, not a child element, so you access it with:

```
p['id']
```